# Jquery Ajax request not reaching the server the second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, web-services, get

I am working on a website, I need to call a service via Jquery ajax to read data.

I am doing the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: "true",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: urlString,
    beforeSend : function (){

    },
    success: function (data) {
        LoadData(data);
    },
    failure: function (request, status, error) {
        alert("Request failed. Please try again later.");
    },
    complete: function () {
    }
});
```

The request is working properly.

However when I call it again with the same URL the request goes directly to the "success" without passing through the webservice. Its like the data was cached from the previous request and it is returning it directly.

For the server side, I am using a WCF webservice with Entity framework 6.0 and stored procedures to read from the database

My questions are :

1. Is this a client behavior or a server behavior?
2. What would happen if the data changes on the server? will I still get the old data because it is cached?
3. if that's the case How can I prevent this behavior? because the data is constantly changing on the server

Thanks for any clarifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Client
2. Yes
3. Use a cache buster, jQuery.ajax does this if you set `cache` to `false`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    async: "true",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: urlString,
    beforeSend : function (){

    },
    success: function (data) {
        LoadData(data);
    },
    failure: function (request, status, error) {
        alert("Request failed. Please try again later.");
    },
    complete: function () {
    }
});
```

Comment: this just saved my day! I had issues with IE 10 caching the ajax and then sending with cache:false helped me fix it

Answer (score 0):

As you are making a Get call, it will get cached by your browser(*client behavior*).
You can use `cache: false` in your call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: "true",
    cache: false,   <---------
```

> Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET
>   requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters

[More Info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)